# Getting incompatible type error on my "while" line

Tags: java

I am getting an error on my while loop stating:

> "incompatible type, int cannot be converted to boolean"

Here is my code, I'm trying to find the average of several numbers using a file.

can anyone tell me why am I getting this error message?

```
//Find the average of several numbers using a file.
import java .io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class inputfile
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
    int num, count=0;
    double sum=0, avg;

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data.dat"));

    while(infile.nextInt())
    {
        num = infile.nextInt();
        sum = sum = num;
        count++;
    }

    infile.close();
    avg = sum/count;
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + avg);
   }
}
```

Comment: while(infile.hasNext())

Comment: What does `infile.nextInt()` return? What type should the expression in `while(...)` be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code below returns an `int`, however the compiler is expecting a `boolean` value.

```
while(infile.nextInt())
```

what you want is this:

```
while(infile.hasNextInt())
```

also, I think you meant this:

```
sum += num;
```

not this:

```
sum = sum = num;
```